# Interface inheritance and abstract method overriding

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstraction

Let's say we have a hierarchy of interfaces: `IBaseThing<T>` and `IChildThing:IBase<ChildThing>`.
Also there are two classes like this:

```
internal abstract class Base<T>
{
    public abstract IBaseThing<T> Thing {get;}
}
```

and

```
internal class Concrete:Base<ChildThing>
{
    public override IChildThing Thing
    {
        get
        {
            return GetChildThing();
        }
     }
}
```

What will happen is as bellow:

> 'Concrete' does not implement inherited abstract member
>   'Base.get'

I want to skip casting `(IChildThing)this.Thing` all over `Concrete` class.
What I supposed to do?

Comment: `IChildThing : IBase<ChildThing>` is an incredibly smelly interface. May be you wanted `ChildThing : IBase<IChildThing>`.. Cant be sure..

Comment: Wrong assumption nawfal. IThings are not T.

Comment: Reza, kindly post the complete example (yet only what is required) and the use case u r after. We could help you better. Otherwise its all assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The type system is rightly objecting to you attempting to change the method type in the overriding class. IChildThing might derive from IBaseThing, but it is not the same thing. For example, you might add some more methods to IChildThing later on. Then one class (Concrete) would be promising a returned object with a different signature than the base class - that's a type error.

If you need to refer to a IChildThing in some cases, how about something like:

```
internal class Concrete : Base<ChildThing>
{
    public override IBaseThing<ChildThing> Thing
    {
        get { return ChildThing; }
    }

    public IChildThing ChildThing { get; set; }
}
```

If all you have is a Base though, then you can't get at the IChildThing safely. That's the nature of a strongly typed system like this. If that's a problem, then if you gave a more concrete example I might be able to suggest how to restructure to avoid that problem.

Comment: I cant figure out the `Thing` property usage now! I'm declaring Thing as a property to be accessible from other classes. Internally this works, but actually you ignored the property philosophy. right?

Comment: What do you mean I ignored the "property philosophy"? I'm not familiar with what you mean.

Comment: We specify a property to provide get and set for other classes, that means private property is not reasonable, instead we can use a private field. In your solution, `IBaseThing<ChildThing> Thing` is not consumable as IChildThing in other classes without casting which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have updated my answer, so that other classes can get at the IChildThing, as well. However, you have to understand that this is done separately from the inherited method - classes that are just expecting a Base<T> won't be able to get at it, and that's just how the type system works.

Comment: I know! I'm looking for a solution to force developers override the get method with proper type. Following your instruction, a developer may forget to write second ChildThing property.

Comment: I think I need more of an example - in this case I can't see why that would matter, as the second property isn't part of any interface, so unless you try and use this specific class somewhere, you won't need the second property. Perhaps you could give a sample of how you are consuming these classes - where you use the properties, instead of just defining them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
public interface IBaseThing {}

public interface IChildThing : IBaseThing {}

internal abstract class Base<T> where T : IBaseThing
{
    public abstract T Thing {get;}
}

internal class Concrete:Base<IChildThing>
{
    public override IChildThing Thing
    {
        get
        {
            return GetChildThing();
        }
     }

     public IChildThing GetChildThing()
     {  
        // Your impelementation here...
        return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as the question?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do, but I've got the above error.

Comment: About the update: Things have to be interfaces. There are some Internal implementation for these public interfaces.

Comment: @Alexander my comment was before your update. Btw I recommend changing type definition to `class Base<T> where T : IBaseThing` or something similar. A constraint would be nice.

Comment: I can't figure out the differences between my question and your answer. Would you please to explain? I'm puzzled.

Comment: @Alexander: Your assumption (where T : IBaseThing ) is not correct bro.
The story is about a repository: T is Entity, IBaseThing and IChild thing are BaseQueryRepository and CityQueryRepository for instance, which are iqueryable providers and are internal. Base and Child are Repositories which use QueryRepositories and return IList<Entity>
So T (Entity) is not about IBaseThing (IQueryRepository)

Comment: @Reza Owliaei, ok, seems, i don't completly clear your question. Please add definition of IBaseThing, IChildThing interfaces and ChildThing class.